# Wordpress the_content() return only one image from a specific category

Tags: php

I am working on a Wordpress website and I am using a loop to get all the posts that have title and body contain an image.

But the problem is that it returns me all the titles but not all the images. I don't understand why.

Here is the code:

```
<?php  query_posts('cat=17&order=ASC');
remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');

if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    ?>
    <div class="photos">
        <?php $args = array('post_type' => 'attachment', 'numberposts' => 34, 'post_status' => null, 'post_parent' => $post->ID);
        $attachments = get_posts($args);
        if ($attachments) {
            foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
                ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $attachment->guid;?>" class="lb_gallery"><?php the_content();?></a>
            <?php
            }
        }?>
        <div class="fotos-desc">
            <span><?php the_title();?></span>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And here is the output on front-end:
[image]

In the above image you can see titles like *foto-1*, *foto-2*, *foto-3* and so on. All these titles are coming through loop but it displays the image for the first one only but all posts are having the image as in the `foto-1`.

Comment: You are probably missing to run `setup_postdata($attachment);` - Also some simple trouble-shooting like `var_dump($attachments);` will actually tell you what data is available and what data is missing.

Comment: i try user suggestion but no luck

Comment: Yes, that was just a quick pointer. Take a look how `the_content` works so that you actually have it output the data you're looking for. Do the `var_dump` as well, there is more you can do to come to a solution, I can not run your code here.

Comment: i think problem is in the array elements when i remove 'post_parent' => $post->ID it give me all but still not the correct one

Comment: Then that does not look good, too. As written, you need to debug this. With guessing after five minutes it's burdensome. Find out what happens and why instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get the ID via `$post->ID`, but that will only return the post ID of the first post. You can use `global $post;` before the args array, or much simpler replace $post->ID by the function `get_the_ID()`.

```
$args = array('post_type' => 'attachment', 'numberposts' => 34, 'post_status' => null, 'post_parent' => get_the_ID());
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem here lies in the fact that you have a nested Loop which is not being terminated correctly. The inner get_posts() is upsetting your outer query_posts loop because you're not resetting this loop when you're done. Try this:

```
<?php  query_posts('cat=17&order=ASC');
remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');

if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    ?>
    <div class="photos">
        <?php $args = array('post_type' => 'attachment', 'numberposts' => 34, 'post_status' => null, 'post_parent' => $post->ID);
        $attachments = get_posts($args);
        if ($attachments) {
            foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
                ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $attachment->guid;?>" class="lb_gallery"><?php the_content();?></a>
            <?php
            }

            // restore loop
            wp_reset_postdata();

        }?>
        <div class="fotos-desc">
            <span><?php the_title();?></span>
        </div>
    </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

All I've done is added a wp_reset_postdata() when you're done with the inner loop to restore your outer one.

Comment: Do **not** use `query_posts`! There's [exactly no reason to do this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts).